# Authenticate/Authorize user based on group with apache and mysql

Tags: mysql, authentication, authorization, apache

I am trying to get authorization to work on my apache installation. I want to authorize depending on what group the user belongs to.

I am using

- Apache 2.2.15
- Centos 6.2 (Running as guest in VB)

My setup is working if I only want to authenticate/authorize based on the user.

Here is the significant part (I think...) of my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Files"
        AuthBasicProvider dbd
        Require dbd-group 1
        Require valid-user

        AuthzDBDQuery "SELECT group_id FROM groupsusers JOIN user ON groupsusers.user_id = user.id WHERE groupsusers.group_id = 1 AND user.users = %s"
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM user WHERE users = %s"

</Directory
```

AuthzDBDQuery doesn't work since, as I understand it, it is not part of any stable version yet. This is the error message I get while starting httpd:

*Invalid command 'AuthzDBDQuery', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration httpd not running, trying to start*

My question is, how can I use groups for authorization when using mysql for storing the groups? I guess it must be possible without re-compiling apache?

Since everything around this is pretty poor documented it would be greate to get some detailed instructions. Of course, anything that can help me in the rigth direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible at this stage. I think it will come support for this in the next stable version of httpd.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I enabled authz_dbd mod in apache 2.4.